# Django: render image from static folder in admin

Tags: django

I need to render a thumbnail image for all my files uploaded in Admin.

I'm using the logo of Adobe Illustrator to show that the files are indeed AI files.

However, it is not beeing rendered. In the HTML I get:

```
<img src="static/img/admin/adobe_illustrator_file_logo.png" width="200px" height="180px">
```

That renders like this:

[image]

**Why?**

```
class OrderItem(models.Model):
    order = models.ForeignKey(Order, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    product = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    quantity = models.CharField(max_length= 200)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2, verbose_name= 'PEN Price')
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='files', blank=True, null=True)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, null=True, default='')
    uploaded_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)



    class Meta:
        db_table = "OrderItem"

    def file_thumbnail(self):
        if self.file:
           return mark_safe(u'<img src="%s" width="200px" height="180px" />' % ('static/img/admin/adobe_illustrator_file_logo.png'))
        else:
            pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a relative path:

```
static/img/admin/...
```

Notice that there isn't any **`/`** in the beginning.

This path is equal to the following:

```python
http://example.com/current/page/url/static/img/admin/...
```

---

**Solution:**

So, you'll need to use **absolute path** (starts with a **`/`**):

```
/static/img/admin/...
```

This will get resolved appropriately to:

```python
http://example.com/static/img/admin/...
```

---

More info on [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_is_a_URL#Absolute_URLs_vs_relative_URLs).

Comment: ty. This will not cause any troubles in production? taking into account that this file will be in staticfiles rather than static, when collect staticfiles will be run?

Comment: @OmarGonzales As long as `STATIC_URL` is mapped to the appropriate directory, it would work as expected.